# get username from Webservice

Tags: c#

How can I get the username from the webservice my Webservice is configured under Enterprise sign on authentication.

I am using the below code for webapplication `Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_CT_REMOTE_USER")`
and I need a equivalent for webservices

```
Context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_CT_REMOTE_USER"]
```

returns null for me

Comment: Whatq web service type are you using? ASMX web service or WCF service? How do your users authenticate against that webservice - integrated Windows Auth? Custom Auth? Forms Auth? You need to give us a bit more information here!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me `Context.Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]`

Answer (score 0):

This works with the later WCF services:

```
ServiceModel.ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name
```

It does NOT work with the classic ASMX services. For those use SSK's solution.